# Uploading Magento2 to another server errors

Tags: magento2, server-setup, magento-2.2.5, upload

I was working with **Magento 2.2.5** using **XAMPP** server on windows. 
I uploaded files to **debian** and imported my database also I maked changes in `core_config_data` and now I have this errors :

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'script': The attribute 'src' is required but missing. Line: 35

Element 'script': Character content is not allowed, because the content type is empty. Line: 35


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'script': The attribute 'src' is required but missing. Line: 35

Element 'script': Character content is not allowed, because the content type is empty. Line: 35

#0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/var/www/html/m...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(141): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load()
#9 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#10 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#11 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(876): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#12 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#13 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'home')
#14 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute()
#15 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#19 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#22 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#28 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#30 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#31 {main}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you removed var folder ?

Comment: No i didn't remove it

Answer (score 0):

Error statement seems that in your code you have used script tag in any of xml file it's not contain src attribute

Please check all custom module files layout files.

If there are many custom module, disable module one by one you will get exact module in which you can find file easily. use below code to disable module

```
php bin/magento module:disable VendorName_ModuleName
```